# C++: Use callback functions as Event notifiers

Tags: c++, events, notifications, event-handling

How I can use callbacks as event notifiers in C++?

I have a function that reads data from an image source. When there's a new frame, I want to fire an event with some data about the frame.

How would you implement something like this in C++?

Comment: use sigslots. its will serve you well

Comment: How does your program know when to read data from image source?  This is when you can call your event functions.

Comment: See *Publisher/Subscriber* design pattern:  [Publisher Subscriber patterns](https://www.google.com/search?q=publisher+subscriber+pattern+c%2B%2B+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too wide, but in general `std::function` and `std::bind` are good candidates for such task. If you cannot/do not want to use C++11 you can use Boost versions. There is a pretty good tutorial here: http://oopscenities.net/2012/02/24/c11-stdfunction-and-stdbind/